# If I click "an edit has been applied to this post", hatz disappear!

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, winter-bash-2014

I just went to a question. It was edited and the banner saying that "an edit has been applied to this post, click to load" appeared. I clicked it and then the avatars of the editor and OP lost their hatz (until I reloaded the page of course). Same with answers.

Halp? HALP!!!

Comment: I believe that also happens to the banner saying that a post is on-hold/closed

Comment: @gunr Yep, as I remember, it is a problem also. But HATZ. It should be fixed immediately!

Comment: Oh noes! You found a hole in the HATS!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not acceptable! Fixed.